# Java - Questions about JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

```
this.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
        {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
            {
                int par1 = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Are you sure you want to exit", "Exit?", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                if(par1==JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
                {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
        });
```

This is my code. How to I set the "No" button in JOptionPane requestFocus?

Comment: Possibly duplicate/similar of http://stackoverflow.com/q/1395707/814074

Comment: @SachinPasalkar No, I want the "No" button selected

Comment: The read the whole question asked by user in above post.

Comment: @SachinPasalkar Oops.......

Comment: Vote to delete....... sorry for duplication...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [JOptionPane.showOptionDialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showOptionDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20int,%20javax.swing.Icon,%20java.lang.Object%5b%5d,%20java.lang.Object%29) and set the `options` and `initialValue` parameters.

```
public static int showOptionDialog(Component parentComponent,
                                   Object message,
                                   String title,
                                   int optionType,
                                   int messageType,
                                   Icon icon,
                                   Object[] options,
                                   Object initialValue)
                            throws HeadlessException
```

Try this:

```
Object[] options = { "YES", "NO" };
int par1 = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Are you sure you want to exit", "Exit?",
    JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE,
    null, options, options[1]);
if(par1==0)
{
     System.exit(0);
}
```

More [JOptionPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use this constructor:

```
JOptionPane(Object message, int messageType, int optionType,
        Icon icon, Object[] options, Object initialValue)
```

`options` represents all available buttons and `initialValue` is the button to be selected by default.